# Limit user input in python

Tags: python

I am new to python programming and stack overflow too. I have to limit user input for the a multiple choice question.ie, a , b, c, d for example. I don't want user to input a character other than a, b, c or d.

```
def test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1

    print("You scored " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(question_prompt)))


test(questions)
```

Comment: You can't. You have to check that the user has given you the correct input manually and ask them again if not.

Comment: Do u know how to fix it with a while loop. Like while it is not a, b, c or d .....print invalid input and enter the answer again ...

Comment: The linked duplicate shows you exactly how to do that, with a number of alternatives.